# Nodejs: Listen on port 80 after using setuid/setgid

Tags: node.js, security, http

I just got convinced by some internet articles, that using setuid/setgid to switch to a lower privileged user might be important. Since I am developing a web app, I decided to go for `www-data`.

So I am using the `userid` NPM module to figure out the user and group ID of www-data, and then change to it. However, when I do that - and it doesn't matter where entirely - I get the following (in this example, the security handler was executed at the very, very bottom of the code):

```
2014-09-04T23:07:05.812Z - info: BIRD3 Security -> Changed to www-data:www-data (33:33)

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1023:19)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at net.js:1146:9
    at dns.js:72:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

As you can see, as soon as I change my privilege level, it drops the accessibility to port 80 too.

Is there a way how I can implement security but keep using port 80 without using [something like this?](https://gist.github.com/gadr/6389682)

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to listen and set the gid/uid?

Comment: @mscdex: Entrence script: http://git.ingwie.me/ingwie/bird3/blob/master/app.js
security_handler.js: http://git.ingwie.me/ingwie/bird3/blob/master/lib/security_handler.js
I commented out the setuid/setgid calls for now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a third-party module to do that. [`process.setgid()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_setgid_id) and [`process.setuid()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_setuid_id) both accept either an ID or a groupname/username.

Also make sure you are dropping the privileges *AFTER* listening on port 80 and that you call `process.setgid()` *before* `process.setuid()`.

Example:

```
var net = require('net');

var srv = net.createServer(function(s) {
});

srv.listen(24, function() {
  console.log('listening');
});

process.setgid('www-data');
process.setuid('www-data');
```

Comment: I did that, and I still got the same error. Also wow, didn't know the native functions supported that. Thanks for that one tho. :)

Comment: What user are you starting the process as before you lower privs?  You will only be able to grab port 80 on startup if you are root or equivalent, and then drop privs after the listener is stood up.

Comment: @Joe I am starting as root:root and then try dropping to www-data:www-data.

Comment: Also make sure you are setting the gid before uid. I've updated the answer to include an example that works for me.

Comment: Isn't the code supposed to run after connecting? So it should be...

`code`
srv.listen(24, function() {
  console.log('listening');
});

process.setgid('www-data');
process.setuid('www-data');
`code`

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the setgid() and setuid() supposed to run after connecting, within the callback response?

```
    srv.listen(24, function() {
console.log('listening');

process.setgid('www-data');
process.setuid('www-data');
    });
```

Comment: Can you chain it like this?
process.setgid('www-data').setuid('www-data')